# If $y\in\mathbb{R}$ and for every positive number $\epsilon >0$, we have $\left| y \right| \le \epsilon$ , then $y=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove or disprove:

If $y\in\mathbb{R}$ and for every positive number $\epsilon >0$, we have $\left| y \right| \le \epsilon$ , then $y=0$

To be honest, I have no idea what is being asked here exactly. The statement does make sense to me since $\epsilon$ is every positive number, hence $y$ has to be $0$. Otherwise, there would be an $\epsilon$ smaller than it.

How do I put this reasoning in a complete and formal proof? I would like for it to be in layman terms as I am new to proof writing. It's very hard for me to wrap my head around concepts like this.

---

Added proof after consultation with answerer:

Proof: We use proof by contradiction.

1) Suppose that $y\neq 0$

2) Let $\epsilon$ be equal to $\frac { \left| y \right|  }{ 2 } $

3) Since $\left| y \right|  \le \epsilon$, we get that: $\left| y \right|  \le \frac { \left| y \right|  }{ 2 } $

4) Then by multiplying both sides of the inequality by $\frac { 1 }{ \left| y \right|  } $, we get that $1\le \frac { 1 }{ 2 } $
This is a contradiction.

5) Therefore, $y$ must be equal to $0$ and the original claim is True.

Comment: Well, if $y \neq 0$, then $\frac{y}{2} \neq 0$, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose by contradiction that $y\neq 0$, then let $\varepsilon:=\frac{|y|}{2}$>0, since $|y|\leqslant\varepsilon$ and $|y|>0$, $1\leqslant\frac{1}{2}$, a contradiction.

Comment: Why did you choose those values for $\epsilon$? You lost me after you stated $y\neq 0$

Comment: Your hypothesis is $\forall\varepsilon>0,|y|\leqslant\varepsilon$, then I'm allowed to choose a precise value for $\varepsilon$ and this is what I've done. Why did I choose $\frac{|y|}{2}$ ? Simply because I wanted to get a smaller real number than $|y|$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. But where did you get $\varepsilon:=\frac{|y|}{2}$ from? and the rest of that whole statement you wrote. It is really difficult for me to see your thought process. Please explain it like you are explaining it to a 5 year old.

Comment: $\varepsilon:=\frac{|y|}{2}$ is just one value among infinitely other I could have chosen to make the proof work. Under the hypothesis $y\neq 0$, I want to construct one $\varepsilon$ which is smaller than $|y|$, this to get a contradiction with $|y|\leqslant\varepsilon$. Indeed, we can't have both $|y|\leqslant\varepsilon$ and $|y|>\varepsilon$. If you don't get it, there is another possible proof, but to me it is more difficult.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I wrote up a proof, but I don't know if it is rigorous enough. Would you be willing to take a look at it if I post it in my original post?

Comment: No problem, I'll do it.

Comment: I added it. Please take a look. Thank you

Comment: I fixed it. It was a typo. I was just rushing to get it written up for you to take a look at it. Is there anything inherently wrong with it? Or does it do the job?

Comment: Everything is now perfect, you can't do better.